# What is the reference of these words

Tags: subjects

In this sentence:

> This film helped the other directors <strike>made</strike> make the films which broke with the bourgeois black film tradition to enter the ghetto and celebrate assertive masculinity and the separatist desire to stick ***it*** to the Man.

1. The reference of "it" is not clear for me.
2. I can't realize the subject of the verb "stick" too.

Comment: Do you understand what "stick it to"  means? If you don't  did you look it up in a dictionary? Because if you had looked it up you would be able to understand better what stick refers to and what the subject is.  [stick it to](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/stick+it+to). And [here](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/stick-it-to-someone).  By the way, I expect you mean "helped the other directors **make** the films"

Comment: The *dummy it* is usually found as a subject.  This is an example of a dummy it as a direct object.  The infinitive phrase doesn't have a subject, but we can find something like an agent.  Separatists stick it to the Man.  Also, it looks like there's a typo.  The past-tense "made" should be the infinitive "make".

Comment: The sentence is stylistically incredibly poor. It's actually not that easy even for competent native speakers to parse, so it's *certainly* not the kind of text learners should be wasting time on. But having said that, ***stick it to the man*** is a very well know idiomatic expression in English. And if you just feed those five words to Google, it'll return plenty of definitions as well as instances of use.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Not to all English speakers!

Comment: @KateBunting: I thought of that possibility immediately *after* posting the comment. So there was plenty of time to do a google search and show that *anyone* (native speaker or learner) could easily look it up, then add a final sentence to my comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Idiomatic slang expression: to stick it to the man

> To take some action intended to defy a source of oppression such as
> globalization, commercialization, big business or government. Paula
> not only told her boss that she quit but also told him to shut up. Way
> to stick it to the man!

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stick_it_to_the_man)